# $.ajax with setTimeout synchronous or asynchronous? total performance?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have seen a code for some chat system which says some thing like below to get the chat messages. I have seen that AJAX is asynchronous. setTimeout here is refreshing the chatlog periodically. So on the whole is it asynchronous communication? $.ajax is synchronous or asynchronous? what is its significance here????

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/

Asynchrounous communication means the server has to send the data to client if there is any new data without the client bugging the server. Isn't it? Please give me a detailed explanation of what's going on below ....... Any better solution how chatlog can be updated automatically with jquery-ajax

if we are checking every x seconds and reloading the whole window again, what is the need to use $.ajax here? just making code complex .... what is the difference between using just php-sql request to the database and setimeout .... cost of the first case: the whole chat is reloaded over and over+ajax call, cost of the second case: whole chat is loaded over and over ... so i don't understand what is the benefit of using ajax according to performance .... in fact i see the later is better...... Isn't it???

```
function updateMsg()
{
$.ajax({
        url:"db.php",
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
        }
});
setTimeout("updateMsg()",7000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default is async :

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the
>   deprecated jqXHR.success().

```
 function updateMsg() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "db.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, //or false
            success: function (data) {}
        });

    }
```

Comment: if it is asynchronous then why do we have setTimeout()? Doesn't asynchronous mean that as soon as a new message is saved in the database, it should send that message to the client, without the client reloading or requesting? Latest Chat messages are only seen with setTimeout()

Comment: I just updated the code with async in order to prove you how it works

Comment: thanks ... but if the above code should update the chatlog with latest messages just by using async:true, then why does the below code in this tutorial use setimeout()? Async means the chat log should be updated whenever a new message is sent... isnt it you say? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/

Comment: For that behavior you need to use another technologies as well, like signal r or websockets or long pooling. Other wise you should check every x seconds for a new message from server

Comment: in that case, if we are checking every x seconds and reloading the whole window again, what is the need to use $.ajax here? just making code complex .... what is the difference between using just php-sql request to the database and setimeout .... cost of the first case: the whole chat is reloaded over and over+ajax call, cost of the second case: whole chat is loaded over and over ... so i don't understand what is the benefit of using ajax according to performance .... in fact i see the later is better ... do you???

Comment: there is no short or definitive answer for that, this is a debate, you should search materials to document on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` param. `async` param determines: is request synchronous or asynchronous

```
$.ajax({
        url:"db.php",
        type:"POST",  
        async: true, // async: false
```

Comment: llya, If there is no async parameter in the above block of code, does it see as synchronous or async by default? Also, just by using async:true param, does the client get the data from the database whenever a new data is added into it without requesting the server?

Comment: @SaKan by default it's `true` and yes

Comment: ok ... if $.ajax is async then server should update the chat messages without client calling settimeout... isn't it? please explain indetail how the above is working

Comment: @SaKan how do you add messages to chat? You should add messages to chat is `success` callback

Comment: llya, yes there should be a method like $.append() or $.html() to add messages to the chat function ... agree.... but my focus here is about deciding if the total thing above is sync or async... the below link says the same code too ... http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/

Comment: @SaKan so what is your problem? In thet link nothing about synchronizing ajax

Comment: I have added another para to my question and also in the discussion to another solution below... Link says the below solution to update the chat log...... "Continuously Updating the Chat Log

setInterval (loadLog, 2500);    //Reload file every 2500 ms or x ms if you wish to change "

Comment: Just above it, says "The jQuery.ajax request ---
The ajax request is the core of everything we are doing. This request not only allows us to send and receive data throught the form without refreshing the page, but it also allows us to handle the data requested.

//Load the file containing the chat log  
    function loadLog(){       
        $.ajax({  
            url: "log.html",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){          
                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div                 
            },  
        });  
    }

Comment: $.ajax{ .......} gets a message asynchronously .. but for the next message to be retrieved, it is loading the whole chat using setimeout()... so the cost is ajax+whole chat reload.... so seen on the whole is this what asynchronous means ????????

Comment: @SaKan synchronous request blocks you page during request is processed. You can do nothing at this time.

Comment: llya.... thank you .. i finally agree to this point ... so suppose the setimeout(x,7000) is set...then you say during that 7 seconds, the page is blocked if we make a synchronous request ... here in this case, we are using $.ajax {} only not to block the page ... is that true ? i know this is not much effective to the overall performance, but makes sense .... isn't it?

Comment: @llya - if true, i agree ... let me know if it is not

Comment: @SaKan "we are using $.ajax {} only not to block the page" yes